# Get more DataTables from an Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

I have this situation with an Excel:

[image]

... I need to read this file but, how you can see, there are two kind of data:

- data (name, surname)... that I can read because I know exactly where they are
- and a table with N rows.

I have some difficulties to read the table.

This is my current implementation:

```
public void Reader()
{
    IExcelDataReader excel = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

    // Fill datatable:
    DataSet dt = excel.AsDataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = dt.Tables["sheetName"];

    // With the position of the cell:
    string name1 = GetCellValue("C2", dataTable);
    string surname1 = GetCellValue("C3", dataTable);
    myLabel1 = name1 + " " + surname1;

    string name2 = GetCellValue("C5", dataTable);
    string surname2 = GetCellValue("C6", dataTable);
    myLabel2 = name2 + " " + surname2;

    string name3 = GetCellValue("F2", dataTable);
    string surname3 = GetCellValue("F3", dataTable);
    myLabel3 = name3 + " " + surname3;

    string name4 = GetCellValue("F5", dataTable);
    string surname4 = GetCellValue("F6", dataTable);
    myLabel4 = name4 + " " + surname4;

    // The table:
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ColumnA");
    table.Columns.Add("ColumnB");
    table.Columns.Add("ColumnC");
    table.Columns.Add("Total");
    table.Columns.Add("Result");

    DataRow newRow;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(9).Take(100))
    {
        newRow = dtSinistri.NewRow();
        newRow["ColumnA"] = row[1]; // I have discover this index with the debug... :(
        newRow["ColumnB"] = row[3];
        newRow["ColumnC"] = row[5];
        newRow["Total"] = row[7];
        newRow["Result"] = row[8];
        dtSinistri.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    myGridView.DataSource = table;
    myGridView.DataBind();
}

/// <summary>Get the value from the cell.
/// For example: 'C5' return "Guybrush"
/// </summary>
private string GetCellValue(string codeCell, DataTable dt)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9]+)(.*)");
    string HDR = "Yes";
    string[] substrings = regex.Split(codeCell);
    string columnLetter = substrings[0];
    int columnNumber = ColumnLetterToNumber(columnLetter);
    int num = (HDR == "Yes") ? 2 : 1; // if first row is an header then num=2, else num=1
    int rowNumber = Int32.Parse(substrings[1]) - num;
    string s = dt.Rows[rowNumber][columnNumber].ToString();
    return s;
}


/// <summary>transform the letter in a column index</summary>
private static int ColumnLetterToNumber(string columnName)
{
    columnName = columnName.ToUpperInvariant();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnName.Length; i++)
    {
        sum *= 26;
        char letter = columnName[i];
        sum += (letter - ('A' - 1));
    }
    sum--;
    return sum;
}
```

...**This works**.
But I want a way to take the table from the excel file in automatic way, like with a query or something else. Any advice?

Comment: Is this process a one shot or you expect receive more excel files like this one ? For the second case, the excel format has been imposed to you or you can propose a better format ?

Comment: I expect to receive a lot of these files. The original template is more complicated and, sadly, is imposed to me

Comment: The format will always be the same ("Name user1" in B2, etc..) ?
What's the extention of the file ? xls or xlsx ?
Do you expect to get text longer than 256 chars ?
=> Be aware that there is a tricky limitation with the default driver of microsoft to read excel files, if the 8 first rows don't have values which length is longer than 256, it will truncate all the values from next rows

Comment: This is just an example. The data that I can take specifing the cell position don't give me any problem, the only problem here is the table... if is possible, I don't want to indicate the indexes for the columns... there is a smart way to get a table from an excel file? So... the file is xlsx. I don't think there will be cells with text longer that 256 chars.

Comment: I used the library LinqToExcel (https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) to query my excel files for one project, but i'm not sure that it'll help you, your case is special, you can't rely on columns index or names, "column a" is the result of fusion of columns B and C.